# oracle merge with

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, common-table-expression

I'm trying to perform an update through the following code:

```
MERGE
INTO    target trg
USING   (
    WITH email AS (
      SELECT trim(t2.crn_0) as cf,
             coalesce(trim(t1.WEB_1),trim(t1.WEB_0)) as im
      FROM   tab1 t1 
      INNER JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.bprnum_0=t1.bpanum_0
      INNER JOIN target t3 on t3.ycodfis_0=t2.crn_0
      WHERE t1.bpaadd_0='000' 
      AND regexp_like(t3.ycodfis_0,'[^A-Za-z]') 
      AND t3.ycodfis_0 != ' '
      AND coalesce(trim(t1.WEB_1),trim(t1.WEB_0)) != ' '
      )
    SELECT email.cf, email.im FROM email
    ) ON (email.cf = trg.ycodfis_0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trg.email_0 = email.im
```

I am getting the following error:

> "EMAIL"."CF": invalid identifier

I tryed to run the only query of the WITH statement, it runs correctly.

I looked at the merge syntax several times, thugh I am not able to find what is my mistake.

Does anybody can help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `email` is used only inside `using` block. Remove it from outside statements:

```
ON (cf = trg.ycodfis_0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trg.email_0 = im
```

Comment: @LucaLeoni you can accept the answer by clicking on the V sign to the right

Answer (score 1):

Always use aliases - for example, `src`:

```
MERGE
INTO    target trg
USING   (
             ... subquery omitted for clarity ...
        ) src
ON      ( src.cf = trg.ycodfis_0 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trg.email_0 = src.im
```